# How to concat two bar charts in Altair with space between series?

Tags: slider, concatenation, bar-chart, altair

I have the following code to generate two bar charts. The first one is a "Central" scenario that needs to be always visible. The second represents multiple stress scenarios with values depending on two sliders.

My problem is to concat the two charts, letting spaces between the two series and making them visible in any cases (like a grouped bar chart).

Here is my code :

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

pvfp=Res.loc[(Res.Item=="PVFP")&(Res.annee>0)]


base = alt.Chart(pvfp, width=500, height=300).mark_bar(color="Green").encode(
    x=alt.X('annee:Q'),
    y='valeur:Q',
    tooltip="valeur:Q"
)
central = alt.Chart(pvfp.loc[(Res.TS=='Central')&(Res.TRA=='Central')], width=500, height=300).mark_bar().encode(
    x=alt.X('annee:Q'),
    y='valeur:Q',
    tooltip="valeur:Q"
)


# A slider filter
TRA_slider = alt.binding_range(min=-40, max=20, step=10,name="Sensi TRA :")
TS_slider = alt.binding_range(min=-20, max=20, step=5,name="Sensi TS : ")

slider1 = alt.selection_single(bind=TRA_slider, fields=['TRA2'],init={'TRA2': 0})
slider2 = alt.selection_single(bind=TS_slider, fields=['TS2'],init={'TS2': 0})

filter_TRA = base.add_selection(
    slider1,slider2
).transform_filter(
    slider1&slider2
).properties(title="Sensi_TRA")

central + filter_TRA
```

And a view of the chart I obtain for now :

[image]

If you have any idea of a way to do that, I would be very grateful.

**UPDATE :**
Here is a reproductible example of the same problem.

```
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd
from vega_datasets import data

dataset = data.population.url
source=pd.read_json(dataset)
source2=df.loc[df.year==1900]


pink_blue = alt.Scale(domain=('Male', 'Female'),
                      range=["steelblue", "salmon"])

slider = alt.binding_range(min=1900, max=2000, step=10)
select_year = alt.selection_single(name="year", fields=['year'],
                                   bind=slider, init={'year': 2000})

chart1 = alt.Chart(source).mark_bar().encode(
    x=alt.X('age:O', title=None),
    y=alt.Y('people:Q', scale=alt.Scale(domain=(0, 12000000))),
).properties(
    width=300
).add_selection(
    select_year
).transform_filter(
    select_year
)
chart2 = alt.Chart(source2).mark_bar(color="green").encode(
    x=alt.X('age:O', title=None),
    y=alt.Y('people:Q', scale=alt.Scale(domain=(0, 12000000))),
)
chart1+chart2
```

As described, what I would like is to find a way to separate the two series and obtain an output like in the example mentioned by @joelostblom

Hope it's more clear

Comment: Do you mean that you want the bars next to each other instead of stacked on top? If so, you can follow this example https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/grouped_bar_chart.html. If not, please clarify in your question and add a reproducible example (I can't run your code because `Res` is not defined)

Comment: The example you mentioned is exactly what I want, but in my case, I have two different charts (one with sliders, one without) and not only one. So I can't handle this with a column argument as described in the example. I'll try to add a reproductible example if it could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a combination of `bandPaddingInner` and `xOffset`. For example:

```python
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd
from vega_datasets import data

dataset = data.population.url
source=pd.read_json(dataset)
source2=source.loc[source.year==1900]


pink_blue = alt.Scale(domain=('Male', 'Female'),
                      range=["steelblue", "salmon"])

slider = alt.binding_range(min=1900, max=2000, step=10)
select_year = alt.selection_single(name="year", fields=['year'],
                                   bind=slider, init={'year': 2000})

chart1 = alt.Chart(source).mark_bar(
    xOffset=-3
).encode(
    x=alt.X('age:O', title=None),
    y=alt.Y('people:Q', scale=alt.Scale(domain=(0, 12000000))),
).properties(
    width=300
).add_selection(
    select_year
).transform_filter(
    select_year
)
chart2 = alt.Chart(source2).mark_bar(
    xOffset=5,
    color="green",
).encode(
    x=alt.X('age:O', title=None),
    y=alt.Y('people:Q', scale=alt.Scale(domain=(0, 12000000))),
)
(chart1+chart2).configure_scale(bandPaddingInner=0.6)
```

[image]